# How to use queue to add floating point numbers in a sorted array?

Tags: assembly, x86

My instructor provided pseudo-code:

```
Q <- empty
for i from 1 to n-1 do:
  x <- smallest of { head(F), head(Q) }
  dequeue(x)
  y <- smallest of { head(F), head(Q) }
  dequeue(y)
  enqueue(x+y) -> Q
return head(Q)
```

where F[n] is a sorted array, and Q is queue where we need to use stack.
 So, we can use push for enqueue, but we need another register to keep track of dequeue position.
From what I understand, if we take `F[5] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 12}`. First, `3+5=8` is enqueued. Then, we compare `8` to `7` and `9`. Since `8` and `7` are the lowest, we enqueue `8+7=15`. Similarly, `9+12=21` is enqueued, but now we have to add it to the previous value in Queue, `15`, to get a total of `36`. The last part confuses me because my instructor told me that Queue should readily have total value.

**edit:** I think my instructor meant to add two smallest floating number, then add two smallest and so on.

Comment: I don't understand the lines dequeue(x) and dequeue(y). What object (container) is being used for the dequeue operations? Also Q starts off as an empty queue, so what does head(Q) return on an empty Q?

Comment: What does this algorithm do, and why are you being asked to implement it this way?  Is this just a way to sum an array with a preference for adding small values first?  What do you mean "Queue should readily have total value"?  At the end?  Or always?

Comment: I was going to ask the instructor but didn't realize until I started doing the question, so I am not sure for now. But I think he meant to add two smallest numbers first, then add two smallest and so on.

Comment: Oh, I guess that makes sense because `F[]` is sorted.  Anyway, are you supposed to / allowed to use the call stack (`[rsp]`) for this?  I guess it doesn't help much other than giving you already-allocated memory, because there's no push/pop for floats to either `xmm` or `st(0)` x87 registers.

Comment: Yes, we should be using stack but as a queue structure.

Comment: Oh right, queue not stack, so it's FIFO not LIFO.  Hmm, using the call stack isn't very attractive then; you can end up needing a lot of memory vs. a circular queue / ring buffer.  But I guess you can't know ahead of time how big the queue needs to be.  Still, just descending the stack is certainly easy, and if you keep a pointer to its original value you can restore it when your function is done.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?  The only thing you've said confuses you is the "readily have total value" thing.  Is that what this question is about?  Looks pretty straightforward to implement with `minss` + `pcmpeqd` to figure out which source the min came from, or more simply a `ucomiss` + branch.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could you tell me how to use `minss`? For example, I can write `minss (%rdi), (%rcx)`. I know that we cannot write memory to memory ,but aside that where does `minss` stores the result?

Comment: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MINSS.html  Look it up in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `F[5] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 12}` the data will look like this:

```
creating empty Q queue, new Q {}

i = 1 (for i: 1..4)
F: {3, 5, 7, 9, 12}
Q: {}
x = 3 from F, new F {5, 7, 9, 12}
y = 5 from F, new F {7, 9, 12}
Q.add(3+5), new Q { 8 }

// next loop
i = 2 (for i: 1..4)
F: {7, 9, 12}
Q: {8}
x = 7 from F, new F {9, 12}
y = 8 from Q, new Q {}
Q.add(7+8), new Q { 15 }

// next loop
i = 3 (for i: 1..4)
F: {9, 12}
Q: {15}
x = 9 from F, new F {12}
y = 12 from F, new F {}
Q.add(9+12), new Q { 15, 21 }

// next loop (last one)
i = 4 (for i: 1..4)
F: {}
Q: {15, 21}
x = 15 from Q, new Q {21}
y = 21 from Q, new Q {}
Q.add(15+21), new Q { 36 }

return Q.head() = 36 (which is sum of original F)
```

The algorithm is designed in such way, that the generated content of Q queue will stay sorted too, just like F is on input, so the smallest available value is always one of the F or Q queue heads, that's why the rule to pick `x` and `y` will check only head of F or Q and pick the smaller one.

So in the actual code you have to code logic for queue methods `.head(), .pop_head(), .push_back()` and use that for two independent queues (F and Q).

If you would want to code for minimal memory usage and if F is already in stack (with smallest values on bottom addresses!): you know F will be only emptying during calculation (no grow) and the total size of F.size+Q.size will be always less than `n`, so you may actually start new Q just under F in memory, and grow it upward, overwriting the original smallest members of F reusing that stack memory for Q elements, then the assembly code will not need any additional memory for processing (it will just destroy the original F array content ... uh, and F input is like array in this case).

I.e. the stack memory from bottom addresses would look like (at beginning/end of each for loop):

```
i = 1 (for i: 1..4) beginning:
stack content (starting at "base" address, dword values, thus *4 in pointers):
    {3, 5, 7, 9, 12}
F[head, end] = [stack_base_adr, stack_base_adr+5*4] ; 5x dword value
Q[head, end] = [stack_base_adr, stack_base_adr] ; empty
    ^^ I mean head/end pointers pairs

i = 1 (for i: 1..4) end:
stack: {8, 5, 7, 9, 12}
F[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+2*4, stack_base_adr+5*4] ; starts at 7
Q[head, end] = [stack_base_adr, stack_base_adr+1*4] ; starts at 8

i = 2 (for i: 1..4) end:
stack: {8, 15, 7, 9, 12}
F[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+3*4, stack_base_adr+5*4] ; starts at 9
Q[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+1*4, stack_base_adr+2*4] ; starts at 15

i = 3 (for i: 1..4) end:
stack: {8, 15, 21, 9, 12}
F[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+5*4, stack_base_adr+5*4] ; empty
Q[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+1*4, stack_base_adr+3*4] ; starts at 15

i = 4 (for i: 1..4) end:
stack: {8, 15, 21, 36, 12}
F[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+5*4, stack_base_adr+5*4] ; empty
Q[head, end] = [stack_base_adr+3*4, stack_base_adr+4*4] ; starts at 36
```

So you need like 4 pointers to keep track of F/Q start/end, and .. well.. simply write it, doesn't look overly confusing or complex to me, most of this will translate 1:1 into assembly instructions, like `mov` to load/store value from queue, and `add` to add values and update pointers of queues. Oh, you have `float` values, so the load/store/add of values themselves will be not `mov/add` integer instructions, but the FP ones (either old x87 or modern SSE2, whichever you want to study+use).

Try to write something, slowly, start for example with empty `for` loop code, learn to use debugger to be able to check if it loops as expected and exits correctly, then add the F queue input, and again check in debugger that inside loop the stack contains values as expected (also decide how you will give the subroutine `n` size of F queue).

Then try just to "pop" values from single queue using only the F head/end pointers, and return the last popped value (12 with sample values). Then try just to pop+sum in temporary and return that (correct 36 as result, but incorrect inner loop implementation "cheating" it).

At that point you should be well into debugging and writing basic asm code, so adding the Q queue code should be doable.

Essential is to learn to use debugger, and add asm code in small steps, watching the result by single stepping each instruction and reasoning what did you write, why, and if it really does what you want (has real purpose toward the target algorithm or the sub-step target as I wrote the sub-steps above, avoid just moving data/pointer here and there without clearly recognizing purpose of each instruction, as that usually leads to bloated, hard-to-debug, assembly code, not making much sense).

Also there's huge difference between hand-written assembly aimed at clarity and simplicity, and hand-written assembly aiming for performance. Sounds like you should aim for the first one. My comments above were meant to show you "design how memory content will evolve during run", which is way of DDD "data driven design" thinking. This way of thinking suits assembly programming particularly well, but don't hesitate to apply it even in high level languages, as doing pure OOP way of thinking sometimes leads to overly complex and stupid designs, re-checking the architecture with data structures in mind may often give you fresh ideas how to simplify the task, or at least gain huge performance advantages just by re-organizing your data structures to suit the target machine architecture better.

... and no, I'm not going to write any asm code for you.